# Alternate between vectors and arrays using templates

Tags: c++, oop, templates

Let's assume that I have a function that prints a set of numbers: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and these numbers can either be stored as an array, or, as a vector. In my current system I therefore have two functions that accept either of these parameters.

```
void printNumbers(std::vector<double> &printNumbers)
{
   //code 
   //....
}
```

And therefore one that accepts an array..

```
void printNumbers(int* numbers)
{
   //code 
   //...
}
```

This seems a waste of code, and, I was thinking that I could better take advantage of code re-use which got me thinking to this: Can I use a template to determine which type of input is being passed to the function? For example, whether it's a `vector` or an `array` or just a single integer value?

Here is the prototype below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
void printNumbers(T numbers)
{
// code 
// code
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   printNumbers<array> (numbers);    
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: `void printNumbers(int* numbers)` - unsafe. You don't know, how many elements in `numbers`.

Comment: @DanielDaranas `error: use of undeclared identifier 'array'
        printNumbers<array> (numbers);`

Comment: @Phorce Then you can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual idiom is to pass iterators, one for the first element of the range, and one corresponding to "one past the end":

```
template<class Iterator>
void printNumbers(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
  for (Iterator i = begin; i != end; ++i)
    std::cout << *i << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() 
{
   int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   printNumbers(numbers, numbers + 5);
   printNumbers(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers); // C++11 version
   std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5};
   printNumbers(v.begin(), v.end());    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm just wondering though, would it be easy to access a single value inside the array using this method?

Comment: @Phorce Possibly. Do you mean a value based on an index?

Comment: Yes! So if I just wanted to add the first two numbers of an array, for example

Comment: @Phorce well, you have to make sure you have at least two elements in the array/vector/whatever. Then you can add `*begin` and `*(++begin)`. But if you want general index access, a slightly different approach is required.

Answer (score 4):

You could follow the example of the STL algorithms and accept an iterator range. Containers have their iterator types, and pointers can be used to iterate over arrays:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void printNumbers(InputIterator start, InputIterator end) {
    // print "*start", and iterate up to "end"
}
```

For convenience, you can overload this to accept containers and arrays directly:

```
template <typename Container>
void printNumbers(Container const & c) {
    printNumbers(c.begin(), c.end());
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
void printNumbers(T (const & a)[N]) {
    printNumbers(a, a+N);
}
```

In C++11 (or with your own `begin` and `end` functions) you can combine these:

```
template <typename Container>
void printNumbers(Container const & c) {
    printNumbers(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```